# VB.Net: open outlook with to,cc,subject, body , attachment

Tags: vb.net, outlook, attachment

i want to open the outlook from my vb.net application. I want to fill out the To,Subject, Body and Attachment part of mail through my application. here i don't need to send mail . I want to just open the outlook with mail parameter.

Please suggest how can i achieve this task

Answer (score 7):

The general procedure is as follows:

- Create a `mailto:` link string with the required information
- Pass that string to [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx). This will open the *default* mail client, not necessary Outlook.

For example, the string might look like this: `mailto:mail@example.com?subject=Hello&body=test`. The individual fields have to be properly escaped (URL encoded). More information about the syntax can be found in [RFC 2368](http://ftp.ics.uci.edu/pub/ietf/uri/rfc2368.txt).

An attachment can be added by using the `attachment` argument in the `mailto` string. According to [a comment on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767737%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) this has to be doubly quoted, though. That is:

```
mailto:mail@example.com?subject=Hello&body=Test&attachment=""C:\file.txt""
```

Comment: Ok i will try and let you know. one more thing. if attachment is more than one then how can this is achieved?

Comment: one more thing, how do you put a newline into your email body using this method?

Answer (score 4):

This task can be achieved using office interop, just add a reference to our projecto to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook'. Then in your applicattion can créate a mail and then attach files as follows:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

...

Dim Outlook As Outlook.Application
Dim Mail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim Acc As Outlook.Account

Outlook = New Outlook.Application()
Mail = Outlook.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)
Mail.To = "test@test.com"
Mail.Subject = "Hello World!"

'If you have multiple accounts you could change it in sender:
For Each Acc In Outlook.Session.Accounts
    'Select first pop3 for instance.
    If Acc.AccountType = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAccountType.olPop3 Then
        Mail.Sender = Acc
    End If
Next

'Take default account if no sender...
If Not Sender Is Nothing Then Mail.Sender = Sender.CurrentUser.AddressEntry

'Attach files
Mail.Attachments.Add("C:\Path\To\File.pdf")
Mail.Attachments.Add("C:\Path\To\File1.pdf")

'Append some text:
Mail.HTMLBody &= "Hello World!"

Mail.Display()
```

It's an old question, but I guess it could help to somebody else.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone wants to do this without using outlook...

```
Imports System.Net.Mail

Public Function SendEmail(EmailBody As String, EmailSubject As String, EmailTo As String, AttachmentPath As String, EmailAsHTML As Boolean)

    Dim Mail As New MailMessage

    Try
        Dim SMTP As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
        SMTP.EnableSsl = True
        SMTP.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("[your gmail address@gmail.com]", "[the associated password]")
        SMTP.Port = 587

        Mail.From = New MailAddress("""[Friendly Name]"" <[your gmail address@gmail.com>")

        'Split Multiple Addresses
        If EmailTo.Contains(";") Then
            For Each EmailAddress In EmailTo.Split(";")
                Mail.To.Add(Trim(EmailAddress))
            Next
        Else
            Mail.To.Add(Trim(EmailTo))
        End If

        Mail.Subject = EmailSubject
        Mail.Body = EmailBody
        If AttachmentPath <> "" Then Mail.Attachments.Add(New Mail.Attachment(AttachmentPath))
        Mail.IsBodyHtml = EmailAsHTML

        SMTP.Send(Mail)

        'Clear Mail Object
        Mail.Dispose()

        'Function Return
        Return True

    Catch ex As Exception

        'Function Return
        Return False

    End Try
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

Found this great post.

[Programmatically adding attachments to emails in C# and VB.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17561/Programmatically-adding-attachments-to-emails-in-C)

The linked article documents how to use the MAPISendMail function provided by MAPI32.dll.

```
    <DllImport("MAPI32.DLL")> _
     Private Shared Function MAPISendMail(ByVal sess As IntPtr, 
         ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal message As MapiMessage, 
         ByVal flg As Integer, ByVal rsv As Integer) As Integer
    End Function

    Private Function SendMail(ByVal strSubject As String, 
        ByVal strBody As String, ByVal how As Integer) As Integer
        Dim msg As MapiMessage = New MapiMessage()
        msg.subject = strSubject
        msg.noteText = strBody

        msg.recips = GetRecipients(msg.recipCount)
        msg.files = GetAttachments(msg.fileCount)

        m_lastError = MAPISendMail(New IntPtr(0), New IntPtr(0), msg, how, 
            0)
        If m_lastError > 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("MAPISendMail failed! " + GetLastError(), 
                "MAPISendMail")
        End If

        Cleanup(msg)
        Return m_lastError
    End Function
```

Hope it will help somebody who might find themselves way here as I did.